# Moq - Specify Parameter Value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to test a method, which relies on the value of one of the fields in my model (used as a parameter).  I'm looking for help on how to mock this value, so my unit test will work.
Without setting this value, the test will follow the path to the exception.

**CONTROLLER**

```
public class StatusViewerController : Controller
{
    private IERERepository _ereRepository;

    //Dependency Injection
    public StatusViewerController(IERERepository ereRepository)
    {
        _ereRepository = ereRepository;
    }



    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "RecordID,ClientNumber")] StatusViewerFormViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                //Send to one of two functions depending on RecordID value 
                if (model.RecordID == null)
                {
                    _ereRepository.StatusViewerInsert(model);
                }
                else
                {
                    _ereRepository.StatusViewerUpdate(model);
                }

                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new HttpException(500, "Internal Server Error");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new HttpException(400, "ModelState Invalid");
        }
    }
}
```

**UNIT TEST**

```
/// <summary>
/// Tests the Edit method for ActionResult return type
/// </summary>
[TestMethod]
public void StatusViewer_Edit_Returns_ActionResult()
{
    //Arrange
    var mockRepository = new Mock<IERERepository>();

    StatusViewerController controller = new StatusViewerController(mockRepository.Object);


    //Act
    //I need to set the value of RecordID here or else this test will fail
    //It will return an exception
    ActionResult result = controller.Edit(It.IsAny<StatusViewerFormViewModel>());


    //Assert
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(ActionResult));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create the model and call the method under test.

What you have not done is setup your dependency for the controller.

```
/// <summary>
/// Tests the Edit method for ActionResult return type
/// </summary>
[TestMethod]
public void StatusViewer_Edit_Returns_ActionResult()
{
    //Arrange
    var mockRepository = new Mock<IERERepository>();
    mockRepository
        .Setup(m => m.StatusViewerInsert(It.IsAny<StatusViewerFormViewModel>())
        .Verifiable();

    var controller = new StatusViewerController(mockRepository.Object);

    var model = new StatusViewerFormViewModel {
        RecordID = "set the value of RecordID here",
        ClientNumber = "Other property value here",
        //...other properties
    };

    //Act
    ActionResult result = controller.Edit(model);


    //Assert
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(ActionResult));
    mockRepository.Verify();//verify that the repository was called.
}
```